# fzf keybindings doesn't work with zsh vi mode

Tags: zsh, zshrc, fzf

fzf ctrl+r doesn't work anymore after I started to use zsh vi-mode. My zshrc file is here:

```
function zvm_config() {
  ZVM_LINE_INIT_MODE=$ZVM_MODE_INSERT
  ZVM_VI_INSERT_ESCAPE_BINDKEY=jk
}
source /opt/homebrew/opt/zplug/init.zsh
zplug "jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode"
# Install plugins if there are plugins that have not been installed
if ! zplug check --verbose; then
    printf "Install? [y/N]: "
    if read -q; then
        echo; zplug install
    fi
fi

# Then, source plugins and add commands to $PATH
zplug load --verbose

[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh
```

If I separately run source ~/.fzf.zsh then it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Adding this command to `.zshrc` solved this issue for me.

```
ZVM_INIT_MODE=sourcing
```

Source: https://github.com/jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode#initialization-mode

Answer (score 1):

fzf keybindings seem to conflict with vi-mode. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2035#issuecomment-707450702), Loading the fzf key bindings after loading the vi-mode plugin is one way to work around this issue. In my case, I was using oh-my-zsh and adding the fzf plugin after vi-mode in the plugins list fixed the issue.

Comment: This didn't work for me.